# Where to put URL in StringBuilder (WebView)

Tags: android

I am encountering a problem where I cannot put the URL in the stringbuilder.  What I am trying to accomplish here is to just get a particular part of the page.  Here is the webpage I am trying to get the content off of:

http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA

Here is the part of the website I want to only show in my WebView:

http://oi44.tinypic.com/2ilnhwi.jpg

Here is my code:

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gb')    .style.visibility= 'hidden';");
        builder.append("document.getElementById('gb')    .style.display   = 'none'  ;");
        builder.append("document.getElementById('appbar').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
        builder.append("document.getElementById('appbar').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
        builder.append("document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
        builder.append("document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
        view.loadUrl(builder.toString());
    }
    }

private void AddListenerOnButton() {
    spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final WebView webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            String text1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD")) {
                //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA");
                wc.onPageFinished(webView, "http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA");
                wc.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, "http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA");
            }
}
```

I have tried everything, but the whole webpage is still showing.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it something else that is wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get specific content off of website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554650/cannot-get-specific-content-off-of-website)

Answer (score 0):

My current code is wrapped in an entire `function()` wrapper, which works fine, maybe you could try that out:

```
builder.append("javascript:(function() {");
builder.append("document.getElementById('gb')    .style.visibility= 'hidden';");
builder.append("document.getElementById('gb')    .style.display   = 'none'  ;");
builder.append("document.getElementById('appbar').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
builder.append("document.getElementById('appbar').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
builder.append("document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
builder.append("document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
builder.append("})()");
```

*Edit: Forgot a couple of parentheses at the end of the `(function(){})`*