# Cannot get specific content off of website

Tags: java, javascript, android

I am encountering a problem where I cannot put the URL in the stringbuilder. What I am trying to accomplish here is to just get a particular part of the page. Here is the webpage I am trying to get the content off of:

http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA

Here is the part of the website I want to only show in my WebView:

http://oi44.tinypic.com/2ilnhwi.jpg

Here is my code:

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gb')    .style.visibility= 'hidden';");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('gb')    .style.display   = 'none'  ;");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('appbar').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('appbar').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
    view.loadUrl(builder.toString());
}
}

private void AddListenerOnButton() {
spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
final WebView webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        String text1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD")) {
            //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA");
            wc.onPageFinished(webView, "http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA");
            wc.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, "http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA");
        }
}
```

I have tried everything, but the whole webpage is still showing. What am I doing wrong? Is it something else that is wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your javascript executed? (Test it with a `alert()`)  
Is it possible that your javascript code will be executed before the site loading is completed?

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.  Maybe if you put the code up, I will understand.

Comment: What happens if you add 
`builder.append("javascript:alert('Hello World');");` after `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");`
Can you see the "Hello World" message in your WebView?

Comment: No, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your code.  It looks like you're trying to use some kind of Javascript trickery to parse out only the data you want (please correct me if I'm wrong).   The problem is javascript is BROWSER-SIDE, so its not running in your page scraper.  You have a couple of options here

1) It seems like you actually want to parse out some piece of information and re-display it on you're site.  Have you considered fetching the page HTML with something like

```
    url = new URL("http://www.your.www");
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

Then using something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse just what you want?

2) You have some control over the size and scale of a WebView [specs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).  Looking at `setPadding` `setScaleX/Y` would probably be a good place to start if you just want to display someone else's page in yours.